# XOR Encryption in Swift IOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, encryption, xor

Trying the convert Below Objective C XOR encryption method to Swift but getting error like "Could nt find overload for 'subscript' that accept supplied argument". Any help would be appreciated.

Objective C

```
+(NSString *) encryptDecrypt:(NSString *)input staticKey:(NSString *) staticKey
{
    const char *key = [staticKey UTF8String];; //Can be any chars, and any size array
    NSMutableString *output = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        char c = [input characterAtIndex:i];
        c ^= key[i % sizeof(key)/sizeof(char)];
        [output appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c]];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Swift

```
func encryptDecrypt(input: String, staticKey: String) -> String {
    let cstr = staticKey.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var output: NSMutableString = NSMutableString()
    for (index, element) in enumerate(input) {
        // for var i = 0; i < input.length; i++ {
        var c: Character = element
        let char = c ^ cstr[index % sizeof(cstr) / sizeof(Character)]
        output.appendString("\(c)")
    }
    return output as String
}
```

Comment: Why not use real encryption, AES from Common Crypto? Here is one fault with XOR: If there is a portion of the data to be encrypted that has all the same value or a known value the key will be exposed with just an offset. In the case I saw there was a preamble of a string of 0x00 bytes and that completely exposed the key. You will still have to check the "uses encryption"but when you go to BIS for the export authorization you will have trouble because you are not using a known encryption method.

Comment: @zaph xor is for key level encryption and it passed to another application for encrypting data using AES

Comment: Making up your own encryption may be fun but it is not secure. [Schneier's Law](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break." For generation a key from a password use PBKDF2. To encrypt keys or passwords use AES.  Use the well better cryptographic primitives (such as NIST standards) and well better security protocols. If you want to play fine, but don't use that to secure others data, doing that would be unconscionable.

Comment: What you're describing is a Vigenère Cipher. Unless or until the 'static key' becomes a one-time pad, it's pretty much no protection at all.

Comment: Spent an hour before found **sizeof instead of strlen**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** *As explained in the comments using this kind of bit manipulation on UTF8 strings is unsafe and will not work as expected for arbitrary inputs.*

I'm actually not sure whether the original Objective-C code does what you want. `sizeof(key)` is the size of the memory address of a `char` pointer (8 on my platform) and not the length of the UTF8 array. On top, `sizeof(char)` should always be 1. You probably want to use `strlen` instead.

Anyways, the equivalent of the (corrected) Objective-C code in Swift 2 could like this

```
func encryptDecrypt(input: String, staticKey: String) -> String? {
    let key = staticKey.utf8
    let bytes = input.utf8.enumerate().map({
        $1 ^ key[key.startIndex.advancedBy($0 % key.count)]
    })
    return String(bytes: bytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

The test snippet

```
let key = "12345"
let string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

let encrypted = encryptDecrypt(string, staticKey: key)!
let decrypted = encryptDecrypt(encrypted, staticKey: key)!

print(string)
print(encrypted)
print(decrypted)
```

will print out

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
PPPPPWU[]_Z^^ZZACAGADDDLLK
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

For Swift 1.2 you'll have to make a couple of small adaptions:

```
func encryptDecrypt(input: String, staticKey: String) -> String? {
    let key = staticKey.utf8
    let keyLength = distance(key.startIndex, key.endIndex)
    let bytes = map(enumerate(input.utf8)) {
        $1 ^ key[advance(key.startIndex, $0 % keyLength)]
    }
    return String(bytes: bytes, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
}
```

**Update:** The following snippet is closer to the original Objective-C code and works for arbitrary strings:

```
func encryptDecrypt(input: NSString, staticKey: NSString) -> NSString? {
    let chars = (0..<input.length).map({
        input.characterAtIndex($0) ^ staticKey.characterAtIndex($0 % staticKey.length)
    })
    return NSString(characters: chars, length: chars.count)
}
```

Comment: There is a major ptoblem with this method: If a valid UTF-8 character is xor'ed with some arbitrary value it may well no longer be a valid UTF-8 character. Try "àbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" or "bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy" as the input string.

Comment: Sometimes your output does not need to be a valid UTF-8 character.  Usually you don't need to read the encrypted data.  Just write it to a file or send over the internet or something and it will be fine when you decrypt it.

Comment: @WolfLink In that case just send the data, don't bother putting it in an invalid UTF-8 string.

Comment: @zaph Isn't that an issue with the original Objective-C code as well?

Comment: Yes, it an issue with ObjC as well. With Swift `let string = "àb"` nil is returned. So this works with the English language (excepting emoji, flags, most currency symbols and many other cases) and not for most of the languages of the world. I have a test implementation in ObjC but did not post it for this reason and also because providing working code of this faux-encryption is like giving dynamite to children, someone is going to get hurt. Oh, and my wife's exact comment about this xor encryption: "That's just stupid".

Comment: @zaph I agree to everything you said. However, the posted question is about translating the (flawed) code from Objective-C to Swift and not about whether or not the code itself should be used in the first place. Hence, I don't understand the down vote.

Comment: Yes, it was me. The down vote for two reasons: 1. It does not work with non-ASCII input. 2. It should not be used. If it is used by someone who sees this answer the ultimate app user's data will be in a compromised state with a false belief it is secure. An up-voted answer tends to encourage potential users that this is a reasonable encryption method. 3. `NSUTF8StringEncoding` potential invalid UTF-8 is an error. 4. My wife's ascertainment of the method. 5. The down vote is just -2 rep, I have up voted a similar answer of your's to compensate.

Comment: Suggestion: Add a disclaimer that the method should never be used because it is insecure and will not work for non-ASCII input.

Comment: I made a mistake when I stated that the question's ObjC code had the same `NSUTF8StringEncoding` flaw as theSwift code in this answer, it does not. The ObjC code while containing errors does not have this one because it never converts the output to UTF-8 or any encoding. Moreover there is at lease one `NSString` encoding that supports 8-bit characters including (I believe) `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`, `NSISOLatin2StringEncoding` and `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding`. Not that the encoded string is necessarily printable.

Comment: @zaph I see. That's a valid concern then. I did not realize that before.

Comment: @hennes, could you give me an idea if i need to encrypt Arabic letters ? what can i use to do that instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`  and `UTF-8` ?

Comment: @AaoIi Doesn't UTF8 inculde Arabic letters?

Comment: @hennes, No it doesn't  and when i try to encrypt it it returns nil.

Comment: @AaoIi I added an alternative implementation at the end of my answer that should work for Arabic characters as well.